# How do I modify IAP OauthClient

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-iap, identity-aware-proxy

I just noticed that two of my projects have the same OauthClient for IAP on GCP.
I want to update one of the IAP resource so that each of my projects got unique OauthClient but I can't find how..
Any help ?

## Workaround

So this ain't a solution but in case it happens to someone else who needs to fix it quicky.

What I did is just delete the common OauthClient. Then deactivate IAP on both my project and reactivate it. New client Oauth had been assign automatically !

Thank you 
:)

Comment: Can you mention which cloud compute product you're using? I would like to answer for future reference to whoever end up here

Comment: I am not sure about what you mean. I am using  IAP on GKE projects. Is this helpful ?